# Como salvar um resultado em txt

Tags: python, random, txt, numeração

Eu tenho esse código que gera umas combinações de números. Quando eu executo ele, essas combinações são imprimidas na tela.
O que eu quero e que ele salve essas combinações em um arquivo txt.

```
import random

c1 = (random.choice([9, 9]))
c2 = (random.choice([1, 1]))
c3 = (random.choice([9, 9, 9]))

def gerar_randomico():
    return random.choice([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

def gerar_randomicus():
    return random.choice([6, 7, 8, 9])

for i in range(3):
    print ('{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}'.format(c1, c2, c3, gerar_randomicus(), gerar_randomico(),gerar_randomico(), gerar_randomico(),gerar_randomico(),gerar_randomico(),gerar_randomico(), gerar_randomico()))
```

Comment: é só tu pegar e salvar os numeros em uma lista, dando um append, e depois criar um arquivo txt e fazer ele escrever.

Answer (score 2):

é só tu pegar e salvar os numeros em uma lista, dando um append, e depois criar um arquivo txt e fazer ele escrever.

O que eu fiz, foi criar uma lista vazia no começo, e no seu for, ao invés de printar, eu guardei o número em uma lista, e ai fiz a criação do arquivo.

```
import random

c1 = (random.choice([9, 9]))
c2 = (random.choice([1, 1]))
c3 = (random.choice([9, 9, 9]))
lista = []

def gerar_randomico():
    return random.choice([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

def gerar_randomicus():
    return random.choice([6, 7, 8, 9])

for i in range(3):
    lista1 = ('{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}'.format(c1, c2, c3, gerar_randomicus(), gerar_randomico(),gerar_randomico(), gerar_randomico(),gerar_randomico(),gerar_randomico(),gerar_randomico(), gerar_randomico()))
    with open('arquivo.txt','a') as arquivo:
        arquivo.write(str(lista1))
        lista_guardar = lista.append(arquivo)
        print(lista_guardar)
```

Comment: Não creio que você deseja abrir o mesmo arquivo com a opção `w`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open ... que tal abrir com `a`?

Comment: verdade, erro meu, já arrumei no código, obrigado pelo toque.

Comment: eu sou extremamente iniciante, nao sei se me expressei bem mas o que eu queria e salvar o resultado em um aquivo.txt, pra esse aquivo txt aparecer por exemplo na área de trabalho do meu pc, eu experimentei esse codigo que vc editou pra mim, mas nao foi o que obtive, se nao for muito abuso gostaria de mais uma ajuda e agradeço vcs por isso.

Comment: na verdade eu achei sim o arquivo txt com o resultado, mas o problema agora foi outro kkkk, dentro do txt os resultados estao um ao lado do outro, nao consegui fazer ficar um em baixo do outro, gerei 3 combinações mas fica uma ao lado da outra em vez de uma em cima da outra.

Comment: Mas porque não pode ser assim ? Quanto tu for puxar do arquivo de texto é só tu dar um split(',') qeu ele irá cortar bem nas virgulas e ti dará o texto limpo.